# class a keyword or a Class?

Tags: java

When we create a class `Class_Name`, we code:

```
class Class_Name
{ 
}
```

Is the word `class` a keyword or it is a Class?

Comment: do you know what is `keyword` ? what it does?

Comment: Keyword is reversed word and that cannot be used as a variable and they have some specified operation.This what I know.

Comment: What you knows is exactly correct. then why you didn't try [here](http://www.google.com) to know about java keyword. This web is very popular. Similarly `class` keyword is very known.... Plus what your question title says and what you asked are different.

Comment: Sorry,I didn't notice that and now I have changed the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word `class` is a keyword. It can be used to denote a class or to get a class object such as `String.class`.

This may be somewhat confusing as there is a class called [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). It's an object that represents a class itself.

For example,

```
Class<?> strClazz=String.class;
```

has the `Class` as a type and `class` as a keyword.

On an unrelated note, the Java documentation calls Class objects `clazz` to avoid conflict with keywords. Also, `Class` is technically a generic in that `Foo.class` will return a `Class<Foo>`, allowing for the lack of covariance to restrict class objects in parameters.

Comment: Where do we use String.class and why do we use that?

Comment: @user1709551 You can use it to acquire a lock usable for static contexts, and/or for reflection.

Comment: Thank you.. I will refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `class` is a keyword to tell the java compiler that you are writing this piece of code as a class. `YourClass.methodname` is used to call methods of a class in a static way.

> When we should call a function using its Class name in Java?

You should do this when you want to call a static method of a class.